# Is there any DVR which can automatically summarize the captured videos? If yes, what are the technologies they use?

Tags: editing

I am doing a research related to video summarization. I found many research papers using various methods for video summarization. What I want to know is that is there any commercial applications with video summarization functionality. (DVR/NVR which has the ability to summarize captured videos)If yes what are the methods they use?

Something similar to [this](https://www.intelli-vision.com/video-summary/)